# Does expected value have a bound?

Tags: probability

I have a question that two NBA team play finals. The first team to win 4 games will be the champion, after which the finals end. Each team wins each game with probability $p=\frac{1}{2}$, independently.

**My question**: what is the expected number of games that each team wins?

**My attempts**:

1. Intuitively, I thought for each game each side won expected value is 2. So, for each side won 4 games should need to play 8 matches.
2. I think there should expected game should be 7 because only 7 games in finals. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "expected value is 2" ----- expected value of what?

Comment: Expected number of wins for each team. I've submitted an edit to make that clear.

Comment: If there are $2^4 = 16$ teams in an elimination bracket (assuming no draws: win or lose only), then after 4 rounds there will be 1 team which wins 4 times no matter what.

Comment: Also, the minimum number of games to be played is 4, as no one can win 4 times in 3 games. So what you have is not a true binomial distribution.

Comment: No, it's a finals series between only two teams. The question is how many games they would play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, there will be an upper bound to the expected value, since a maximum of $7$ games can be played

Using the formula $\Bbb E[X] = \sum np,$ summing over $n = 4$ through $7$,

$\Bbb E[X] = 2[4p^4 +5\binom41p^5 + 6\binom52p^6 +7\binom63p^7] = \boxed{5.8125}$

Comment: Nice, I also use excel to verify probability and all sum up to 1. However, I stuck why expected value is 2.9. Now I see your way is more make sense. We should count the otherside also will have probabilities to win this game!

Comment: Glad to be of help !$\;$ :-)

Answer (score 0):

7 is the *maximum* number of games that can happen, not the *expected* number of games. The expected wins for each team is half of the expected number of games (since each team expects to win half the games), so the expected number of wins will be less than $\frac{7}{2}$. Similarly, the *minimum* number of games that can happen is 4, so the expected number of games has to be more than 2.

I'm not sure what the best way to solve this is. Since there's only 4 possible outcomes (4, 5, 6 or 7 games), it might be easiest to just use the expected value formula directly. That is, calculate $\sum_{n=4}^7 n\times P(\text{there are $n$ games})$.